# how to Convert Color to HTML color in .NET Standard 2.0?

Tags: html, .net, colors, .net-standard-2.0

how Convert  Color to  HTML color in   .NET Standard 2.0, thank u.

is that any way to perform the same function in .net Core similar to the code below:

```
System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(color);
```

in DotNet Framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what is your actual question,
By the way, just let you know that,
The

```
System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(color);
```

do supported by Dotnet Framework from Ver 1.1 to 4.8,
Refer to Microsoft Document (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.colortranslator.tohtml?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

Comment: thank you ....my application use the Framework sdk is .NET Standard 2.0  so  i cannot use System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml

Answer (score 0):

I have adapted the following code to do this based on the original [System.Drawing.ColorTranslator](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Advanced/ColorTranslator.cs,bf4fe372fd7fd3c9) source code:

```cs
public static string ToHtml(System.Drawing.Color c)
{
    var xResult = string.Empty;
    if (c.IsEmpty)
    {
        return xResult;
    }
    xResult = ((!c.IsNamedColor) ? ("#" + c.R.ToString("X2", null) + c.G.ToString("X2", null) + c.B.ToString("X2", null)) : ((!(c == System.Drawing.Color.LightGray)) ? c.Name : "LightGrey"));
    return xResult;
}
```